# How to sort all fields in an object using only one Comparator?

Tags: java, comparator

How to sort all fields in an object using a single comparator?

Ex: If I have an `Employee` object with three fields such as `Name`, `Eid` and `Salary`. Instead of writing three comparators i.e. `Namecomparator`, `Eidcomparator` and `Salarycomparator` for sorting, I need only only one comparator that can sort based on the filed I provide dynamically.

Comment: It is clumsy. Use some libraries like Google Guava instead (or Java 8).

Comment: Un-neat code that does the trick should look something like that: `if (o1.field1 < o2.field2) return -1; else if (o1.field1 > o2.field1) return 1; else if (o1.field2 < o2.field2) return -1; else if (o1.field1 > o2.field2) return 1; else if (o1.field3 < o2.field3) return -1 else (o1.field3 > o2.field3) return 1; else return 0;` The idea is to use multiple if-else condition in the desired comparison order (most important field first)

Answer (score 9):

> Instead of writing 3 comparator's i.e., Namecomparotor, Eidcomparotor and Salarycomparotor for sorting, I need only only one comparotor that can sort based on the filed I provide dynamically.

Using Java 8, and if all those fields have a `get` method, you can use [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-)

```
Collections.sort(employees, Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary);
```

And if you want to sort by multiple criteria (to break ties), you can use [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-)

```
Collections.sort(employees, Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary)
                                      .thenComparing(Employee::getName)
                                      .thenComparing(Employee::getId));
```

In both cases, you just pass the field to sort by as a `Function` to create a custom `Comparator`. Alternatively, you can also use a [`lambda` expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to sort by all kinds of other criteria:

```
Collections.sort(employees, Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getName.length()));
```

---

In case you are using an older version of Java (and can not upgrade to Java 8), you could make your own `Function` class and an according generic `Comparator`:

```
abstract class CompareFunction<A> {
    abstract public Comparable apply(A object);
}

class FunctionComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    final CompareFunction<T> function;
    public FunctionComparator(CompareFunction<T> function) {
        this.function = function;
    }
    public int compare(T a, T b) {
        return function.apply(a).compareTo(function.apply(b));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Collections.sort(employees, new FunctionComparator<Employee>(new CompareFunction<Employee>() {
    public Comparable apply(Employee object) {
        return object.getSalary();
    };
}));
```

Or combine it with Java Reflextion to create such a comparator based on the name of a getter method:

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> createGetterComparator(Class<T> clazz, String getterName) throws Exception {
    final Method getter = clazz.getMethod(getterName);
    return new FunctionComparator<T>(new CompareFunction<T>() {
        public Comparable apply(T object) {
            try {
                return (Comparable) getter.invoke(object);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
Collections.sort(employees, createGetterComparator(Employee.class, "getSalary"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Similarly is there any way to sort in Java 1.6 or 1.7

Answer (score 5):

Use something like sort by id, then name then salary:

```
public class EmployeeComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        if (e1 == e2) {
           return 0;
        } 
        if (e1 == null && e2 != null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (e1 != null && e2 == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (e1.getId().equals(e2.getId())) {
            if (e1.getName().equals(e2.getName())) {
                if (e1.getSalary() == e2.getSalary()) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return int(e1.getSalary() - e2.getSalary());
                }
            } else {
                 return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
            }
        } else {
            return e1.getId().compareTo(e2.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

If you need concise version of above, you will need to either use [Guava's ComparisonChain](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained) as below:

```
    @Override  
    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {  
        return ComparisonChain.start() 
           .compare(e1.getId(), e2.getId(), Ordering.natural().nullsLast()) 
           .compare(e1.getName(), e2.getName(), Ordering.natural().nullsLast()) 
           .compare(e1.getSalary(), e2.getSalary(), Ordering.natural().nullsLast()) 
           .result(); 
   }
```

or [apache's CompareToBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) as below:

```
public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {  
    return new CompareToBuilder().append(e1.getId(), e2.getId()).append(e1.getName(), e2.getName()).append(e1.getSalary(), e2.getSalary()).toComparison();  
}
```